# UIActionSheet warning message in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I am trying to show `UIActionSheet` from `UINavigationController` in iOS.

When i use `[action showInView:self.view];` they showed me warning messages like following.

```
Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].
```

However UIActionSheet is showing correctly and nothing happened.

In my iOS , i support Landscape mode like following code.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0 ||
        UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        [action showInView:self.view];
    } else {
        [action showInView:self.view.window];
```

I like to know that warning messages is important?

Or Can i ignore that warning messages?

Comment: Is the nav controller showing a toolbar? Is there a tab bar involved? Use the proper "show..." method based on the answers to these questions.

Comment: This message means - UIAlertView's buttons could be covered with UIToolBar. Just try to add more buttons, you won't be able to click on some of them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your navigation controller showing a toolbar? If so, the bottom 44 points of the action sheet will likely not respond. To solve this, use `[action showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar]` (just like the error message says).

The same applies if your navigation controller is in a tab bar, but then you should use `[action showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar]`.

Comment: Also, when you click outside an action sheet it should dismiss/cancel the action sheet, but if you don't do this, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
  [action showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
} else {
  [action showInView:[self.navigationController view] ];      
}
```

it will save you lot of trouble with UITabBarController etc. Also it should fix the warning message.